# iOS autolayout to center my view between two views

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

How to set up autolayout in Interface Builder to arrange views vertically as shown on image:

[image: scheme]

`Top view` pinned to top screen edge, `Bottom view` pinned to bottom screen edge. `My view` should be centered between top and bottom views (so distance to `Top view` equals to distance to `Bottom view`)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The way to do this is to have 2 invisible "spacer" views between you visible views.

You can't make spaces have equal height. But you use the "spacer" views and place them between your views (with 0 gap to the surrounding views).

Then you give these views equal heights and they will push your views around to centre the `My View` with equal gap to the `Bottom View` and `Top View`.

i.e. like this...

```
V:|[Top View][spacer1][My View][spacer2(==spacer1)][Bottom View]|
```

**EDIT - Another way**

I just thought of another way of doing this. You could have an invisible container `UIView` that is between `Top View` and `Bottom View` with no gap.

Then you place `My View` inside this invisible view and centre it vertically.

Comment: Why not just keeping equals top and bottom views' height and centering the middle view in the parent?

Comment: Well that would work. Except that isn't what the question is. The image in the question clearly shows the top and bottom views with different heights. Also, it asks about centering a view exactly between two views. It doesn't ask about centering a view in its superview.

Comment: Ops, you're totally right didn't notice the difference in height between the views

Comment: Fogmeister, thanks. At last, could you suggest how to adjust view position when I already set correct constraint values (Interface Builder proposes me to adjust constraints to match view position but I want conversely)?

Comment: @brigadir Yeah, in one of the buttons in the bottom right of Interface Builder it has options for "Update frames to match constraints" and also "Update Constraints to Frames". You want this second one.

Comment: I think he was saying that "Another way" was better than the original answer, not that there was a third way that was better. :)

Answer (score 57):

One more solution is to add an invisible view between *top view* and *botom view* and place *my view* in center of this view:

[image: Centered UIView]

Comment: Such a genius hack! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 24):

(5 years later) I've found the most canonical solution:

**`UILayoutGuide` is specially introduced to solve this kind of tasks (since iOS 9).**

*Use layout guides to replace the dummy views you may have created to represent inter-view spaces or encapsulation in your user interface* - [Ref docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide)

It works pretty fine in code, but unfortunately Interface Builder doesn't support custom layout guides.

Comment: I can't believe I'm discovering this until now (:facepalm:). Thank you so much!

Comment: Some example code would be great