# iOS: Have equal space between 3 dynamic objects within a container view

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have a XIB set up like so:
[image]

The left side button is set at 50x50, the right side imageview will be dynamic and the center view and embedded imageview is also dynamic. What I am looking to do is keep equal space between the end objects and the middle one. So, as the size of the right imageview grows or shrinks, the middle view adjusts its x point to keep the space equal between both end objects.

I'm trying to do this without code if possible but can't seem to figure out a way to accomplish it.

Edit: I've rethought this and I think I can accomplish what I need by pinning the leading edge of the middle view to the trailing edge of the button and the trailing edge of the middle view to the leading edge of the right image view. I am hoping that as that right image view grows or shrinks the middle view will do the opposite.

My problem right now is if I add those pins the xib layout falls apart, not sure why. See the images below of before pinning and after.

No constraints:

[image]

Here I placed top, leading and bottom constraints of 0 on the button, leading and trailing constraints of 1 and top/bottom constraint of 0 on middle view and top, bottom and trailing constraint of 0 on right image view. The xib loses height or it's y is now moved down and the right view blows up to fill the screen up to the button's trailing edge.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add spacer views between the middle item and the outer items and set constraints to keep those spacer views the same width.

Similar to this question:

[iOS autolayout to center my view between two views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024759/ios-autolayout-to-center-my-view-between-two-views)

Comment: I had tried that (the Another Way) solution - but whenever I add constraints it blows my UI up. (see images I posted)